# In Postgres is it possible to bin all numerical data?

Tags: postgresql

I have a DB that has some of my analytics data, I was using pandas for a lot of my work but I am curious if I can do this directly in Postgres. What I'm trying to do is take only the numerical data and bin it.

Here's a pandas example for demo:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Bob", "Mary", "Amy"], "Age": [22, 35, 58], "EarningsYearly": [100,200,50],})
#let's bin...
df['percentage']= df['Age']/df['Age'].max()
bins = [.0,.25,.50,.75,1.00]
labels = [1,2,3,4]
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['percentage'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df

    Name    Age EarningsYearly  percentage  binned
0   Bob 22  100 0.379310    2
1   Mary    35  200 0.603448    3
2   Amy 58  50  1.000000    4
```

Note, in this example I'm binning percentage but I want to bin all numeric data

If I have this table in postgres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE please_help (
   section TEXT NOT NULL,
   num1     NUMERIC ,
   num2     NUMERIC 
);
INSERT INTO please_help
SELECT sections.*, gen.*
     , CEIL(RANDOM()*100) 
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 300)     sections,
       GENERATE_SERIES(1, 900000) gen
 WHERE gen <= sections * 3000;
```

I researched this and I think maybe [width_bucket](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) can do this? But I couldn't figure out how to apply it to all columns (or even one).

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: I am not sure about your question, but Haki Benita has written about binning that you might find helpful: https://hakibenita.com/sql-for-data-analysis#binning

Comment: @DanielLidström many thinks, this is what I'm asking about, I'm just not sure how to apply it to all numerical values or a list of values?